# Proof $\{(x,y,z)|4x^2+9y^2+16z^2<1\}$ is an open set

Tags: calculus, general-topology

In order to prove that the points $(x,y,z)$ such that

$$4x^2+9y^2+16z^2<1$$

form an open set, I tried this:

Pick a generic point of the ellipsoid, lets say 
$$4x^2+9y^2+16z^2$$

Now, I'll form an open ball around this point. It's an open ball such that $4x^2+9y^2+16z^2$ is the center, and the distance from $4x_0^2+9y_0^2+16z_0^2$ (another point of the open ball) is some $r$. So we should have:

$$4(x-x_0)^2 + 9(y-y_0)^2 + 16(z-z_0)^2<r$$

In order to pick the $r$ I must imagine the ellipsoid and pick its 'radius' (in this case, the greatest 'radius' possible) which I think its $\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore we end up with:

$$r = \frac{1}{2}-4x^2+9y^2+16z^2$$ (in other words: $r = \frac{1}{2}-||(x,y,z)-0||$

I just have to end up with the inequality $4x_0^2+9y_0^2+16z_0^2<1$, which proves that any point of my open ball is in the ellipsoid (an ellipsoid without the 'shell').

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Think of some point inside the ball and then set some radius for a neighborhood around it . If you want you can also show that every neighborhood around every boundary point cannot be contained in the set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever $f(x,y,z)$ is a continuous function $\{(x,y,z):  f(x,y,z) < 1  \} = f^{-1}([0,1)) $ is not necessarily open since $[0,1)$ is only [half-open](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-ClosedInterval.html).

In fact, your set can also be written $\{(x,y,z):  f(x,y,z) < 1  \} = f^{-1}((-1,1)) $ which is definitely open.

---

One strategy is just to let $r \ll 1$ and then your ball fits in the ellipse.  $$r < \mathrm{min}\left[ \frac{1}{2}- |x_0|, \frac{1}{3}- |y_0|, \frac{1}{4}- |z_0|\right] $$

---

Another strategy.  Let $0  < \Delta x < \epsilon \ll x $  then for one coordinate axis only we have:

$$  x^2(1 - \epsilon)^2 < (x+\Delta x)^2 < x^2(1 + \epsilon)^2   $$

then we can combine the result for all 3 axis to arrive at our result:

$$ 
 0< 4(x+\Delta x)^2 
+ 9(y+\Delta y)^2
+ 16(z+\Delta z)^2
< (1+\epsilon)^2 [4x^2 
+ 9y^2
+ 16z^2] < 1
$$

Notice we can always solve for $\epsilon$ so so that we remain inside the ellipsoid.

Comment: But how I would proceed to prove by using this radius?

Comment: Could you help me in the proof by using the radius you provided?

Answer (score 0):

$f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}, (x,y,z) \mapsto 4x^2+9y^2+16z^2$ is a continuous function, and the set you want to find is the preimage of the open interval $(-1,1)$ (and the preimage (w.r.t. a cont. function )of an open set is always open).

Answer (score 0):

The map $f: \mathbb{R^{3}} \to \mathbb{R}$ (with respect to the Eucldian metric), $f(x,y,z)=4x^{2}+9y^{2}+16z^{2}$ is continuous. (This follows from the fact that the map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $t \to t^{2}$ is continuous). Now, the set you're given is the inverse image of the interval $]-1,1[$, and under continuous maps, the inverse image of an open set is open.

Comment: It might also be that the OP hasn't yet learned the notion of continuity

Comment: Yes, I haven't learned it :(