# Prove a set is open set with open ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let S = $\{(x,y,z)|3x^2+4y^2+5z^2 < 6\}$ 
I want to show this set is open by proving that S completely encloses some open ball for arbitrary point $x_0$ in S.

My solution so far: 
Let $x_0$ be in $S$ such that $x_0 = \{(x,y,z)|3x^2+4y^2+5z^2 < 6\}$. 
Let $r = 6$ and define an open ball $D_r(x_0) = \{k\in \mathbb{R}^n  |   \|k-x_0\| < 6\}$. 
I am not sure how to continue from this step, can anyone help?

Comment: As you have ellipse i.e. almost sphere, then you have distance from taken point to border. Decrease it and use as radius of small open ball.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in S$, can you show that there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$S_0(\varepsilon)=\{(x,y,z); 3(x-x_0)^2+4(y-y_0)^2+5(z-z_0)^2<\varepsilon\}\subseteq S?$$

Once you show this, you're basically done, since
$$(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in \{(x,y,z); (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2<\frac\varepsilon5 \}\subseteq S_0(\varepsilon),$$
so this means that an open ball of radius $\varepsilon/5$ around $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is inside the set $S$.

---

It might be also useful to check various similar questions which have already been posted on this site:

- [Proof $\{(x,y,z)|4x^2+9y^2+16z^2<1\}$ is an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1342271)
- [Show that the set $E=\{(x,y):x^2+2y^2<6\}$ is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1516116)
- [Determine whether the set $B = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | 3x^2 + 2y^2 \lt 6 \}$ is open or closed and calculate its boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3549817)
- [Prove set $\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^{2} : \frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}<1\right\}$ is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1395932)

(You can probably find many other questions asking for a proof that some relatively simple set is open. These are the ones that I was able to find relatively quickly and are about an ellipse or an ellipsoid.)

Answer (score 0):

I bring analytical solution for $\mathbb{R^2}$. Let's take $x^2+y^2\lt R^2$ disk and consider any $(x_0,y_0)$ from this disk i.e. $x_0^2+y_0^2=r_0^2\lt R^2$. Now we can show, that for any $(x,y)$ with $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\lt (R-r_0)^2$ holds $x^2+y^2\lt R^2$:
$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\lt (R-r_0)^2 \Leftrightarrow \\
x^2+y^2+2(Rr_0-xx_0-yy_0) \lt R^2$$
because expression in parentheses is positive.

More easy solution is to consider polar (spherical coordinates).

As to your ball with radius $\lt 6$, then it will not work for points close enough to border.